# Accent sensitive matches in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, character-encoding, special-characters

MySQL table is recognizing `cód` and `cod` as same. How can i avoid this problem.
The table is `COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'`

Comment: Is it for a particular national language that you need to treat O and Ó as lexically different letters for the purpose of matching? They're treated the same in Spanish.

Comment: yes it is for Spanish but I want to keep them separate. i want to know how many users write O and Ó in our business logic

Answer (score 3):

You should look for the characters set, tablename, and column names of the fields you want to use

Make sure they are set to:

```
COLLATE='utf8_bin'
```

Make sure you don't put the `_ci` at the end as it stands for case insensitive

If you can't get to the table and db in the database, you can use it on your queries:

```
SELECT * FROM tablex WHERE LOWER(column) = 'cód' COLLATE utf8_bin
```

Comment: It's worth noting that MySQL allows per-column collation as well.